# Outsourcing the dashboard for others - how to keep the privacy but can still fixing the bugs of the report?

Tags: powerbi, share, privacy

I need your help.

I create a dashboard for another sector of our company. The data for the dashboard is from google docs, and people from that sector edit it daily (sometimes changing the name of the columns or removing the column), which makes me manually check twice per week to make sure that the dashboard is okay.

After the dashboard was created that sector doesn't want me to continue accessing their data. Is there any solution that: 1/allow me to check the dashboard when it has problem(s) 2/minimize my access to their private data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want to be able to check the report you will need access to the workspace. If you can't have access to the data, then a new report owner who does have access to it will have to take it over from you.

The only other way would be to create a copy of the google docs, with anonymised data, for column changes. You base a report on that, change the connection settings, then deploy it to the workspace. But if you can deploy it, you can technically access the live data in the work space.